# I received UK Visa refusal due to deposits I made in my account just before taking bank statement. Need advice fro applying again

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

[image]I received UK Visa refusal due to deposits I made in my account just before taking bank statement. Actually first 17 months from April 2018 until September 2019 I received salary in cash, 70125 SAR from which I saved liquid cash 12000 SAR which i deposited in bank. Since September 2019 my salary account was opened by the company, and this is the main refusal point mentioned by ECO. so all my savings which is hardly 10-12% of my net salary I deposited in bank. But I dint mention anything about it.

All my other documents stating my salary slip / traveling itinerary etc were accepted.

For new application : I got the letter from my employer that since when I was receiving my salary in cash. 
I also obtained the exit and reentry visa (as its mandatory in KSA for expat) which clearly sates my traveling period and reentry in KSA.

This evidence is enough to prove my case? What should be my cover letter?

Secondly fro example I have submitted 10 documents in my previous application and they raised red flag for two. In new application I will provide same 10 documents with more evidence to prove my case. So is their any chance they raise red flag about some other document from the 10 which I submitted before and now as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) Pay particular attention to the section titled "Funds Parking, Lifestyle, and Credibility." This thread may also be useful: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: it is helpful, but still i hope to get more detailed advise.

Comment: IN fresh application, I am not going to show case any sponsor, as I do not need any.

Comment: Both of the linked questions at the top of the page will help you. Keep in mind that it is very difficult for people who are paid in cash to obtain UK or Schengen visas. You may wish to consider being paid by bank transfer if your employer will do this, or by cheque.

Comment: I was paid in cash only during first 17 months (its the policy to pay in cash until we finish probation), and I worked with Sheraton Hotel and our CEO has given the letter mentioning about how many months I used to receive cash salary. Now I am already having my salary getting transferred in Bank account. so it can be useful?

Comment: IMHO you’d be better to wait a few months before reapplying. Unless you have a compelling reason to visit the UK, reapplying quickly after a refusal can make it appear that you are desperate to visit, which an ECO might find suspicious. Waiting a while will allow your financial background regarding receipt of salary to settle down and be easier for the ECO to understand. If you just want to visit the UK as a tourist waiting a while shouldn’t matter that much, you can visit other places meanwhile to improve your travel history profile.

Comment: Thank you for your advice Sir. But actually this is my annual vacation and upon my request my company arranged accommodation and flight bookings, also my Saudi reentry visa is stamped. So I have to take this chance or else I will loose this opportunity to visit. Anyhow fingers crossed.